# How to force update the version number of an sbt application in IntelliJ IDEA / SBT?

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

Whenever I update the `version` variable in my `build.sbt` file, either SBT or IDEA doesn't recognize the change and so after I compile and package the program, it shows the old version number in the file name.

Clicking "Force refresh all linked sbt projects" in IDEA doesn't update the version number.

I tried `sbt-buildinfo` as a workaround but it shows the old version number as well.

Comment: Does it update version if you run "sbt package"  from command line?

Comment: No, it doesn't. The old version number gets placed in the file name. Since posting this question I realized that if I restart sbt console in IDEA it finally picks up on the version number change. Is that normal behavior (do I really need to refresh the console between each version change)?

Comment: Do you invoke `reload` or `reboot` after you change the version number? SBT build definitions are in Scala and compiled down to JVM bytecode, so for SBT to pick the new version up, the classes have to be recompiled. This happens either when you restart SBT, type `reload` ("shallow" restart) or type `reboot` ("deeper" restart). It is more common to use `reload` when you change anything in your build definition.

Comment: Thank you, `reload` works and that answers my question.